# Story about night vision people living underground hunted by giant slug creatures

Tags: story-identification

Posting for a friend. The story is about a group of people who live underground and are hunted by giant slug creatures. They can see in the dark. Apparently there is a hero amongst them who once killed a slug, and is considered legendary. The truth is that he is in fact blind, and killed the slug by accident.

Likely from the 60s or 70s, and I don't know if it was a novel or a short story.

Comment: I don't think this is your book, but it has some of the same elements.https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3199832-the-hero-of-downways The Hero actually died, and the creature he killed isn't a slug (don't want to post spoilers) You might like it anyway. They can see into the infra red, which is what I assume you mean by night vision.

Comment: Also sounds similar to Silverberg's _At Winter's End_, but again there are elements that don't match up. Eg at the start of the book there were giant slugs encroaching on the underground settlement where everyone lived, but I don't recall anything about a hero that killed one of the slugs.

Comment: "The Hero of Downways" is correct.  Confirmed with my friend.  Thanks @sueelleker